# Runing gridmix2 in hadoop 2.0.0 cannot initialize Cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloud

It's my first time using hadoop and try to run gridmix2 with it. I had installed hadoop 2.2.0 but when I try to generate data with gridmix i had the following error:

**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.**
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomTextWriter.run(RandomTextWriter.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomTextWriter.main(RandomTextWriter.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)


at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

But in my file hadoop-env.sh i found that:

**

```
# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
    if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
        export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
    else
        export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
    fi
done
```

**

and the problem is that the contrib/capacity-scheduler doesn't exist in my system.

Thanks for your help!